# Use Func<> as a property?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I have this class that I use to validate controls:

```
public class Validation
{
    public object Control { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Func<Control, bool> Custom { get; set; }

    public Validation()
    {
        //How to set Custom??
    }

    private bool IsValid()
    {
        Control c = Control as Control;
        if (c != null)
        {
            return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Text));
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The class simply checks that a control's `Text` property contains text.

Now I want to extend the class so that particular forms using this class can set their own custom method for validating a particular control.

Question: How to I set the `Custom` property to be a method (either the default `IsValid` or a custom method located in the calling form?)

Comment: Your function has the wrong signature to match that `Func` property. You are expected to pass in the control as the first argument, but instead, it takes the control from the class.

Comment: Why don't you make `IsValid` virtual and let each derived class override the method?  Am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite a little, since `IsValid` doesn't have a valid signature for the `Custom` function.

What about this?

```
public Validation(Func<Control, bool> isValid = null)
{
    //How to set Custom??
    Custom = isValid ?? this.IsValid;
}

private bool IsValid(Control c)
{
}
```

You can pass in a custom implementation for `isValid` through the constructor. If it is null, it will use the `IsValid` method in your class.

Comment: How to I call the method? (as in `if (myValidation.Custom) {}` ?

Comment: `myValidation.Custom(c)` or `myValidation.Custom.Invoke(c)`.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems your question is a little confused. As I understand it, your `IsValid()` method wants to call the `Custom` function if there is one.

So I guess in the calling `Form` you want to do something like that:

```
Validation myCustomValidation = new Validation { Control = myTextBox };
Custom = ctl => ctl.Text == "validText";
```

And your implementation of `Validation.IsValid()` could look like:

```
private bool IsValid()
{    
    Control c = Control as Control;
    if (c == null) return true;

    if (Custom != null) return Custom(c);

    return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Text));
}
```

So in the calling `Form` you can provide a lambda or method for custom validation. And your `IsValid()` can decide to call this (if it is set) or use its default implementation.